# Is it possible to use something like top.window.name

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assign the window.name of the iframe holder, when your script is inside the iframe? Something like "top.window.name" will give an error.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, if the iframe is hosted at the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Otherwise, permission to top window's properties is denied.

Also note that `top.window === top`, so you may use `top.name`, or `window.top.name` to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Have to get the parent document:

```
parent.document.getElementById("textFromTitle").innerHTML;//for example
```

You could also use:

```
window.parent
```

However, I believe in both these scenarios the iframe must be on the same domain in order to share this type of access.